# Why are my subclass's __getitem__ and __setitem__ not called when I use [:]?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, slice, python-internals

I am working on Python 2.7 and I am trying to overload  `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` from a class that inherits `list`.

Let's say I have this class `A`:

```
 class A(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print "GET!"

   def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "SET!"
```

With square brackets, `A.__getitem__` or `A.__setitem__` should be called. Normally it is like that, but when I use `[:]` the parent implementation is called instead. Why? And why does `[::]` work?

```
a = A([1])
a[1] # prints GET!
a["1"] # prints GET!
a[::] # prints GET!
a[slice(None)] # prints GET!
a[:] # returns the list [1]
```

And the same with `__setitem__`:

```
a[1] = 2 # prints SET!
a[::] = 2  # prints SET!
a[slice(None)] = 2  # prints SET!
a[:] = [2] # changes the list
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because in Python 2 <sup>[1]</sup> `[:]` as well as 1-d slices with *start* and/or *end* (but not when *step* is specified) like `[1:]`, `[:3]`, or `[1:3]` go through [`__getslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) and [`__setslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setslice__) if they are implemented. If they are not implemented they will also go to `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`). Quoting from the docs:

> Notice that these methods [`__*slice__`] are only invoked when a single slice with a single colon is used, and the slice method is available. For slice operations involving extended slice notation, or in absence of the slice methods, `__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()` or `__delitem__()` is called with a slice object as argument.

In your case you **inherit** them from `list` (`list` implements them) so it bypasses your `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` in simple slice situations.

As an example, you could override the `__*slice__` methods to verify that the `[:]` call really goes there:

```
class A(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print "GET!"

   def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "SET!"  

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        print "GETSLICE!"

   def __setslice__(self, i, j, seq):
        print "SETSLICE!"
```

However these are only called when just one slice is passed in and only if the passed slice doesn't have a step. So `[::]` won't go there because it has a step (even though it's implicit). But also `[:,:]` wouldn't go into these because it is translated to `tuple(slice(None), slice(None))` which isn't a simple slice but a tuple of slices. It also doesn't go into these `__*slice__` methods if you pass in a `slice` instance yourself, that's why `[slice(None)]` even though seemingly equivalent to `[:]` directly goes into `__*item__` instead of `__*slice__`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> In Python 3 the `__*slice__` methods were removed so there the `[whatever]` indexing will go to the `__*item__` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However I do not understand the case of `[::]`. At keys I receive an `slice(None)` not a `tuple`, the same happens with the case of giving the `slice` directly `a[slice(None)]`

Comment: The `[::]` implicitly contains a step (even though it's equal to the default one) so it cannot go to `__*slice__`.